# Insert a value from one object to another object in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom

I'm currently building a page which allow user to enter information on VF. The VF page is using one of the custom object called "Quality_Evaluation__c", then I also have another junction object "Quality_Evaluation_Question_Weight__c" which is the master details with question and weight custom objects. In the junction object, I have a lookup field for storing the Quality_Evaluation__c record id. I'm trying to put a logic in my save method. See below:

```
if(this.QualityEvaluation.Status__c == 'New' && (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null || ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != ''))
{
    this.QualityEvaluation.Status__c = 'Pending Submission';
    insert this.QualityEvaluation;
}
```

After insert, record ID is created of this object. However, I would like to assign this record ID into the Quality_Evaluation__c field from the Quality_Evaluation_Question_Weight__c in the same method. So I can display the data back on the VF page in the controller.  My question is how to assign this record ID into this field?

I also have a wrapper class which wrapping the junction object. Would that be good to create a method in the wrapper class, and pass the parameter

```
public list<QualityEvaluationQuestoinWeightWrapper> copyID(Id id,Quality_Evaluation_Question_Weight__c qw)
{
  // copy the id into the junction object
  return list;
}
```

Comment: After an insert, the Id field is automatically populated in the reference in the Apex so you can assign this.QualityEvaluation.Id to the Quality_Evaluation__c field of the Quality_Evaluation_Question_Weight__c instance.

Comment: a picture of your schema would be helpful